# Ajax - push and pull?

Tags: ajax

I would like to learn about Ajax push and pull concepts. If there is any tutorial or book, I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I cleaned up the language a bit for you. Feel free to reverse the edit if you prefer it the other way. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a nice [A Comparison of Push and Pull
Techniques for AJAX](http://swerl.tudelft.nl/twiki/pub/Main/TechnicalReports/TUD-SERG-2007-016.pdf) for you.